# email tableView text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, mfmailcomposer

i know how to add in app email, but i dont know how to email the text of my table view. I do, but my problem is that when the user adds a cell to the table, how do i get that to print out too? 
to print out the text normally i would use

```
string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ \n %@",[array objectAtIndex:0], 
                                                           [array objectAtIndex:1], 
                                                           [array objectAtIndex:2]];
```

and i set the email Body to string. Does anyone know how to make it to where if a new cell is added, i can get it to be added to the email body as well??

Thanks

Comment: So you want to print(or email) the text of the cell if the user taps the cell?

Comment: yeah i want to add the tableViews text or cell's text to the email's body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem but here goes . . .

You can make your code deal with more than a fixed number of items like this :

```
string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" \n "];
```

If `array` is also the data source for your table view then `string` should then contain all the table cells with a break between them.

---

You can only update the body of your email in an MFMailComposeViewController *before* you have shown the email view to the user - once it's been displayed then it's read only :(

Comment: ok this works perfect!! but i have a plist that populates the table and i stored the contents of the plist into an array called "cells" so i said: string = [cells components...]; and it prints out some extra stuff like keys in my plist? do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that your array is populated with string objects.

Compose the string:

```
NSString *theMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ \n %@,", [array objectAtIndex:0], [array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Now, assuming you also have an instance of **MailViewController**, instantiated as *mailViewController*, write this code in for the body:

```
[mailViewController setMessageBody:theMessage isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: Thought I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: yes this is what i  had but my users can add cells and i wanted that text to be printed out too and it works with string = [cells components...]; thanks a lot though! :D

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working in a different way. Mind dropping some sample code in here - I may need to implement something similar very soon.

Comment: Yeah well good luck! if u need any help with implementing the email view then let me know i have the code all written out! :D

Answer (score 0):

First populate the `UItableView` formatting the strings with the methods indicated over, then in your:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
UITableViewCell *cellView = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];//Section 0  
NSString *string=cellView.textLabel.text;
//compose email body with string
```

Hope this helps.